# Android SwitchPreference not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences, switchpreference

I'm trying to retrieve the SwitchPreference's value using SharedPreferences but it isn't working. I'm using SwitchPreference so that user can turn on/off notifications, but it shows notifications no matter whatever the value is.
Here's the code.

NotificationUtils.java

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (preferences.getBoolean("notification_key", true)) {
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID + rowId, notBuilder.build());
    }
```

preferences.xml

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:contentDescription="Turn notifications on/off"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="notification_key"
    android:summaryOff="Off"
    android:summaryOn="On"
    android:title="Notifications" />
```

I also have overridden and registered the OnSharedPreferenceChange listener in SettingsFragment.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, actually the value wasn't toggling, in settings screen the Switch was turning off and on but the value remained the default. Solved it by setting the new value in OnPreferenceChangeListener and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

I believe you're attempting to retrieve `"notification_key"` from the wrong `SharedPreferences`, which is why it's always using the default value of `true` and showing your notification.

*Edit:* You can check to see whether the `SharedPreferences` you're using contains the "notification_key" key with the [`contains()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: I've used the getDefaulSharedPreferences(context) method but same thing happens, checked with contains method if the key exists and that returns true. When using getBoolean method whatever boolean defValue I provide is gets set and shows notifications, if set to true no matter whatever the switch's state is and, if defValue set to false then it doesn't show notifications even if the switch state is on. I just can't figure out what's going on there.